# Past tense of " I have to"

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-perfect

Question 1: How do I change this correctly and accordingly to the past perfect tense

example: He have to do that because someone has told him to

possible answer: He had to do that because someone had told him to

Is that correct?

Question 2: Can I use two had in a sentence. Like , can I use "had" on the past action after previous past?

Comment: One does not say "He have to do that". The correct form is "He has to do that." or "You have to do that."

Answer (score 1):

### Question 1

This is correct! You could also have said,

> He had to do that because someone told him to.

Because “told” is already past tense.

### Question 2

Similar to question 1, you could either use two “had”s or one “had.” For example,

> He had had a bad day yesterday.

versus

> He had a bad day yesterday.

In the first example, one “had” is the past-tense possessive, and the other one describes an event that happened in the past (like the “had” used in question 1).

Hope this answers your questions!